# formula field in apex

Tags: workflow, formula

HOW TO write a formula in workflow so that whenever status is in open/reopen state 
populate the custom field to today's date and if the status changes the the field should be null

```
IF(AND(
if(status = open/reopen/ then customfield = todays date)
 else
 {
  NULL
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Workflow field update, choose the Custom field and put the formula in the editor.

```
IF(
  ISPICKVAL(status,"Open") 
  || ISPICKVAL(status,"reopen"), 
  TEXT(TODAY()),
 ""
)
```

It will return `2017-04-25`.

If you want to return `4/25/2017` (mm/dd/yyyy) format use this:

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Status,"Open") || ISPICKVAL(Status,"reopen"), 
     TEXT(MONTH(TODAY())) & "/" + TEXT(DAY(TODAY())) & "/" & TEXT(YEAR(TODAY()))
,"")
```

Note: it has been assumed, custom field is text field.

Comment: I have a datetime field CaseStatus__c to be updated ..... but i am getting  Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'IF()'. Expected Date, received Text
ERROR....inside the formula field update.....

Comment: updated the formula

Comment: @Kiran Santanu meant NULL instead of "", I presume.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also : -

```
IF(
  OR(   
  ISPICKVAL(status,"Open"), 
  ISPICKVAL(status,"reopen")), 
  TODAY(),
 ''
)
```